# The process size increased when less aggregated columns in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I have my virtual base table as follows

```
WITH orders AS (SELECT
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m', orders.order_placed_localtime_at) AS Month
  , entity_id
  , country_code
  , order_id
  , customer_id
  , items.sku
  , items.global_product_id
  , items.value_euro.total_price
  , items.value_lc.total_price_lc
  , items.qty_sold
  , warehouse.warehouse_id
  FROM `my_db.orders` AS orders
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(items) AS items
  WHERE TRUE
    AND DATE(ordered_at) >= '2022-01-01'
)
```

When I run this query to aggregate the unnested query, the returned processing size is  around 30 GB

```
SELECT
    Month
    , orders.entity_id
    , orders.country_code
    , COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS totalOrders
    , SUM(qty_sold) AS qty_sold
  FROM 
    orders
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

However, when I took out the last aggregation, the returned processing size is 500GB

```
SELECT
    Month
    , orders.entity_id
    , orders.country_code
    , COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS totalOrders
  FROM 
    orders
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

That seems really weird to me. Does anyone experience this and any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: No, this should not happen. Please clean up your query and do not use the same name for the array and the items of it. Also do not use `orders` twice.  `FROM my_db.orders AS my_orders, UNNEST(items) AS item`   Is the entry  `warehouse.warehouse_id` is another join not listed?

Comment: @Samuel Thanks for the reply first! 
True, the name of the order should be changed.
For the warehouse, it is another nested document.

Meanwhile,  regarding the issue, I also think it does not make sense, but somehow it does happen...